# cat command loading file

Tags: unix, cat

Does cat command load the entire file into main memory?

```
for i in `cat file.txt`; do
    # some logic on i
done
```

Will this code has any performance issue when the file is large say 5-6 GB?

Comment: @pixelbeat has the right answer.  Additionally, you might consider just piping `file.txt` to a script that takes stdin.  What is the logic you are performing in the loop?

Comment: I am trying to read a large file line after line. So which approach would be better.

Comment: The logic in the loop is to get data based on a delimiter and insert it into database

Comment: If you are loading into a database, then it's probably fine to use the supplied answer below, since performance of the loop infrastructure isn't going to be significant compared to the database insert.  However, if you have a huge file, you may want to consider some batch import functionality on your database, since row-by-row inserts of 5-6 GB will take a LONG time.

Answer (score 3):

`cat` doesn't load the whole file in, but the process substitution in your for loop above will

If you have one entry per line you could instead:

```
while read line;
    # some logic on $line
done < file.txt
```